# Java - GeoLite2 database corruption when creating .jar in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, geolite2, geolitecity

Recently I have been using GeoLite2 City database in my application to get information on the user location using their IP. The database works fine in my local machine, but when I compile it to a .jar using `./gradlew -Pprod clean bootJar` I get this error when trying to access a component that uses the database:

```
InvalidDatabaseException
Could not find a MaxMind DB metadata marker in this file (<InputStream>). Is this a valid MaxMind DB file?
```

Searching for this error, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449733/geolite2-database-gets-corrupt-when-added-to-jar) on StackOveflow that explained the need to disable resource filtering for binary files in Maven. Thing is, I'm using gradle, which as far as I know, does not have this resource and should not be facing this problem.

Regardless, I tried searching for a solution and tried implementing something based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698167/gradle-include-jar-without-filtering-binary-newlines) to fix the issue. I ended up adding this to my build.gradle:

```
processResources {
    from('src/main/resources/data') {
        include '**/*.mmdb'
    }
}
```

That, however, also did not work. It seems like this should be a simple issue, but I have not been able to solve it and neither did I find someone with the same issue so far. Any help would be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (note: I did not test it)

```
processResources {
     filesNotMatching("**/*.mmdb") {
         
     }
 }
```